# Build libcurl for arm-linux-gnueabi: Why curl ignores openssl?

Tags: curl, openssl

#### 1. Build openssl

```
git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git -b OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable --depth 1 openssl-1.1.1
cd openssl-1.1.1
./Configure --prefix=/usr linux-generic32 shared  \
      --cross-compile-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
make depend -j7
make -j7
make DESTDIR=/Volumes/lpd-dev/armhf/ install_sw install_ssldirs
```

#### 2. Build curl

```
git clone https://github.com/curl/curl.git -b curl-7_64_1 --depth 1 curl-7.64.1
cd curl-7.64.1
./buildconf
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --prefix=/usr --with-ssl=/Volumes/lpd-dev/armhf/usr
```

this outputs:

```
...
configure: PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR will be set to "/Volumes/lpd-
dev/armhf/usr/lib/pkgconfig"
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for openssl options with pkg-config... found
configure: pkg-config: SSL_LIBS: "-lssl -lcrypto"
configure: pkg-config: SSL_LDFLAGS: ""
configure: pkg-config: SSL_CPPFLAGS: ""
checking for HMAC_Update in -lcrypto... no
checking for HMAC_Init_ex in -lcrypto... no
checking OpenSSL linking with -ldl... no
checking OpenSSL linking with -ldl and -lpthread... no
configure: WARNING: SSL disabled, you will not be able to use HTTPS, FTPS, NTLM and more.
configure: WARNING: Use --with-ssl, --with-gnutls, --with-polarssl, --with-cyassl, --with-nss, --with-schannel, --with-secure-transport, --with-mesalink or --with-amissl to address this.
...
```

pkgconfig was found, but WARNING: SSL disabled

Answer (score 0):

During writing the question I reread ones more `./configure`'s output and understood that "/Volumes/lpd-dev/armhf/usr/lib/pkgconfig" points to `--prefix=/usr` but since we are cross-compiling is points to wrong location!

Simply move or remove `.../armhf/usr/lib/pkgconfig` fixed problem.

```
    ...
curl version:     7.64.1-DEV
SSL:              enabled (OpenSSL)
SSH:              no      (--with-libssh2)
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for your sharing! I met the same issue, but I can’t figure out what did you modify to fix this — what did you mean regarding “Simply move or remove .../armhf/usr/lib/pkgconfig fixed problem.” ?